# Rails app is failing with "Bad Handshake"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I got a rails app which is failing with a bad handshake.

I believe it's something to do with the mysql library, I can access most of the app fine, however when I run into a page which uses ferret it fails.

I think it has something to do with me running RVM. The gems are installed and the version of rails if fine for my user, but the ferret script is started with this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

on the command line, if I do, ruby -v it comes out with the right version.

which I think is using a different ruby, since it might not be setting the paths right?

Below is the output I am seeing in the production log file.

note: localhost:9010 IS the host and port of the ferret server.

```
ActionView::TemplateError (#08S01Bad handshake) on line #38 of
layouts/_sheet_info.rhtml:
35: 
36:   <%= worked_nice(@current_sheet.duration/60) -%><%= info_string -%
<%= " - " if total_today > 0 %>
37: <% end %>
38: <% if total_today > 0 %>
39:  <%= distance_of_time_in_words(total_today.minutes) %> <%=_ 'worked
today'%>
40: <% end %>
41: 


(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/vendor/mysql.rb:523:in `read'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/vendor/mysql.rb:153:in `real_connect'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:527:in `connect'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:186:in `initialize'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:85:in `new'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:85:in `mysql_connection'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:292:in `send'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:292:in `connection='

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:260:in `retrieve_connection'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:78:in `connection'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1143:in `table_exists?'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1222:in `inspect'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:143:in `rebuild_index'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:171:in `reconnect_when_needed'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:142:in `rebuild_index'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:165:in `with_class'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:138:in `rebuild_index'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:123:in `ensure_index_exists'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:165:in `with_class'

(druby://localhost:9010) /...myapp../vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/ferret_server.rb:119:in `ensure_index_exists'
   vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/remote_index.rb:16:in `send'
   vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/remote_index.rb:16:in
`method_missing'
   vendor/plugins/acts_as_ferret/lib/act_methods.rb:189:in
`acts_as_ferret'
   app/models/work_log.rb:6
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because the script running to setup ferret was running as another user. Also rebooted the machine which could have helped.